# Disable inertia in unity when rigidbody climbs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As you can see in the gif below, the character moves when I hit left and right on my keyboard. If I release left and right, the character will stop moving as expected.

Im using this code for the horizontal movement:

```
rigidbody.AddForce(x,0,z)
```

My problem is that when I try to use this code

```
rigidbody.AddForce(0,y,0)
```

for vertical movement, the character climbs the wall just fine but when I release the up or down key, the character has **inertia**.

Why has horizontal movement no inertia but vertical does?

[image]

---

**Update:**

I can use

```
rig.MovePosition();
```

instead of AddForce, but the question is still their. Why does AddForce in horizontal movement not result in inertia but AddForce for vertical movement does?

Answer (score 0):

I find the reason, in character object inspector > animator, I enable "apply root motion", here is [root motion](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RootMotion.html) doc, it say:

> The Root Transform is a projection on the Y plane of the Body Transform and is computed at runtime.

**so I guess "apply root motion" will only work in xz axis,**

so move in horizontal has no inertia, it's unity magic, when i disable 'apply root motion', addforce to move will has inertia

in my case, climb is move in y axis, and in physics, addforce in most case has inertia
so "apply root motion" doesn't work, so if i wanna disable inertia, the solution is use rigidbody#MovePosition instead of AddForce